# how can generate trimester dates in python?

Tags: python

I try to generate dates of trimester from two dates date_from and date_to, I tryed with a function but that only shows me the dates from the actual year
Like this example
date_to = '2021-05-01'   date_from = '2022-05-01'
the result is
date_to = ['2021-01-01','2021-04-01','2021-07-01','2021-10-01]
date_from = ['2021-03-31','2021-06-30','2021-09-30','2021-12-31]

my function is this:

```
data = {}
line_cost = [(5, 0, 0)]
month = datetime.strptime(str(self.date_to), '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%m')
year = datetime.strptime(str(self.date_to), '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y')
aux = 0
for num in range(1,5):
    x = int(num)+aux
    date_from = str(year)+'-'+str(x)+'-'+'01'
    aux += 2
    y = int(num)+aux
    periodo = calendar.monthrange(int(year),y)
    date_to = str(year)+'-'+str(y)+'-'+str(periodo[1])
    for lines in self.as_plantilla.template_cost_lines:
        data = {
            'date_from': date_from,
            'date_to': date_to,
        }
        line_cost.append((0, 0, data))
```

And The correct result should be this
date_to = ['2021-05-01','2021-08-01','2021-11-01','2021-02-01]
date_from = ['2021-07-31','2021-10-30','2021-01-31','2021-04-29]

Comment: I'd recommend working with datetime objects, and only render strings for IO

Answer (score 0):

You need monthly `timedelta`s to work not only with actual year. But python's `timedelta` doesn't support months.

`relativedelta` from `python-dateutil` package supports months. Also `pandas` has `MonthBegin`, `MonthEnd` to work with months.

```py
from pandas import Timestamp, date_range
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthBegin, MonthEnd

start_ts, end_ts = Timestamp('2021-05-01'), Timestamp('2022-05-01')
starts = date_range(start_ts, end_ts - MonthEnd(3), freq='3M') + MonthBegin(-1)
ends = date_range(start_ts + MonthEnd(3), end_ts, freq='3M')
list(zip(starts, ends))
```

output

```sh
[(Timestamp('2021-05-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-07-31 00:00:00', freq='3M')),
 (Timestamp('2021-08-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-31 00:00:00', freq='3M')),
 (Timestamp('2021-11-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-01-31 00:00:00', freq='3M')),
 (Timestamp('2022-02-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-04-30 00:00:00', freq='3M'))]
```